# Using thread two part of a program differently

Tags: c#, multithreading, pacman

I'm actually coding a pacman (C# Console) i would like to know how to move my ghost each seconds, but i would also like to be able to move my pacman whenever i want.

I would like my ghost keep mooving each second whatever pacman do, i should be able to move pacman when ever i want, and ghosts just have to move every second.

I guess i have to use Thread system, so i would like to know if you know how i have to proceed and how thread works, can't find any information about that :s.

Comment: `Console Pacman` : Have you considered using [XNA](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_XNA) ?

Comment: I did ^^ but i need to use Console Application for school

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: @JohnSaunders I love how everybody refering to this question phrase it the exact same way.

Comment: i think, that's fine without threading. ex : move_pac();
move_ghost();
print();

Comment: this is what i want to avoid, i won't the ghost wait any pacman action to moove

Comment: @PhaDaPhunk: I'll consider it to be "sincere flattery".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably confused because `Console.ReadKey()` is **blocking**...so your game loop would be stuck waiting for the user to press a key right?  What you do is only grab the keystroke with ReadKey() if there is already one in the queue.  This can be checked with `Console.KeyAvailable` which returns true if a key is already there.  This way the game loop just keeps looping around if no key has been pressed...but you can still trap it and do something with it.  Try this quick example out and see what happens:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(250);
            Console.Write(".");
            if (Console.KeyAvailable)
            {
                ConsoleKeyInfo key = Console.ReadKey(true); // read key without displaying it
                Console.WriteLine("");
                Console.WriteLine("Key Pressed: " + key.KeyChar.ToString());
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to use different threads for each ghost. This can all be done on one thread using a [Game Loop](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_programming#Game_structure)

> The central component of any game, from a programming standpoint, is
>   the game loop. The game loop allows the game to run smoothly
>   regardless of a user's input or lack thereof.
>
> Most traditional software programs respond to user input and do
>   nothing without it. For example, a word processor formats words and
>   text as a user types. If the user doesn't type anything, the word
>   processor does nothing. Some functions may take a long time to
>   complete, but all are initiated by a user telling the program to do
>   something.
>
> Games, on the other hand, must continue to operate regardless of a
>   user's input. The game loop allows this. A highly simplified game
>   loop, in pseudocode, might look something like this:
>
> ```
>    while( user doesn't exit )
>      check for user input
>      run AI
>      move enemies
>      resolve collisions
>      draw graphics
>      play sounds
>    end while
> ```
>
> The game loop may be refined and modified as game development
>   progresses, but most games are based on this basic idea.

Follow that pattern and your game will be much easier to write.

Comment: Problem is, if i do decide to do not mooving my pacman, the ghosts will be freeze to :s

Comment: That is not how it works. Moving pacman would be in the `Resolve Collisions` step. If pacman is not moving that function just does nothing that loop.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found what i do need :
[Threads and Thread Synchronization in C#](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/26130/Threads-and-Thread-Synchronization-in-C%20%22MultiThreading)